# Standards-compliant way of returning JWT authentication token in JSON-LD encoded response body?

Tags: rest, security, authentication, jwt, json-ld

I am working on a REST service that speaks JSON-LD and uses JWT authentication. I would like to know if there is a standard-compliant way of returning the JWT token to the client after an authorization GET request (similar to what's described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938733/8295283) post), but then formulated as JSON-LD.

In the example the authentication request returns:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "access_token": "NgCXRK...MzYjw",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_at": 1372700873,
    "refresh_token": "NgAagA...Um_SHo"
}
```

I would like to have something similar, except the media type should be `application/ld+json` and the information in the response body not some custom format, but formulated in a standards-compliant manner.

Does such a standard notation exist, and if not, how could I describe this semantically with JSON-LD in a way that conveys its meaning and makes sense?

(Note: In my search I found all kinds of JSON-LD notations that come close, but not suited for returning a JWT .. I think).